# PHP strtotime / date_create bug converting from "j M, Y" to "Y-m-d"

Tags: php

I have a bug with strtotime and date_create. In my code, it is incorrectly converting a date from "07 Sep, 2014" to "2015-09-07". Note the year is wrong!

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$listing_date = "07 Sep, 2014";
print $listing_date . " --> ";
$listing_date = date_create($listing_date)->format('Y-m-d');
print $listing_date . "\n";

$listing_date = "07 Sep, 2014";
print $listing_date . " --> ";
$listing_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($listing_date));
print $listing_date . "\n";

?>
```

...and here is the output:

```
07 Sep, 2014 --> 2015-09-07
07 Sep, 2014 --> 2015-09-07
```

Am I doing something wrong? Advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: u must remove comma from your $listing_date ;

Comment: Works perfectly now, thank you!

Comment: If that comma is the problem then why is thi code working? `echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("07 Sep, 1991"));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you must remove `comma` from `$listing_date` or change new format to`'Y-m,d'` Also such a situation you should use [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to achieve credible results.

Comment: If that comma is the problem then why is this code working? `echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("07 Sep, 1991"));`

Comment: The question was different Mr. Wonko used  date_create function.It's return DateTime object, so this code related to php version. I just answer spesific question. It's not important